# Language dependent ORDER BY in JPA/SQL

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using Hibernate as JPA provider with named queries and wondered if there is a native way to order results language dependent. The underlying database is some Oracle R10.

Let's say you have a Table animals that has an english name column and a latin name column (and maybe many more .. french, german, italian, spanish) and you have to sort depending on  one of the languages.

To get a ordered list you could use different select statements like these

```
SELECT animal from Animal animal order by animal.name_EN;
SELECT animal from Animal animal order by animal.name_LA;
SELECT animal from Animal animal order by animal.name_FR;
```

and so on. Or what I did was to write a Comparator to sort the result list depending on the language.

Is there a better, more elegant way to get this done?

Comment: The query is as elegant as it can be. But the database design is not. Is it the database design that you want more elegant?

Comment: Something like ORDER BY name_:lang would be nice. An i18n database query that natively orders my results depending on a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead os adding a column for each language in your table, you should normalize and have an additional table ANIMAL_TRANSLATION:

```
ID : technical ID, auto incremented
ANIMAL_ID: foreign key to the ANIMAL table
LANGUAGE: the language of this translation
NAME: the translated name
```

You would then have a OneToMany association between Animal and AnimalTranslation:

```
public class Animal {
    /**
     * The translations, indexed by language
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "animal")
    @MapKey(name = "language")
    private Map<String, AnimalTranslation> translations;

    ...
}

public class AnimalTranslation {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ANIMAL_ID")
    private Animal animal;

    ...
}
```

And your query could be, for example:

```
select translation from AnimalTranslation translation
inner join fetch transalation.animal animal
where translation.language = :language
order by translation.name;
```

And this would retrieve all the animal translations, with their animal, for a given language.

This might seem more complex, but it's also more normalized, and doesn't force you to change your schema and entities each time a new language comes in.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thanks a lot for this inspiration!